# why web part that i created for SPS cannot be use in SFS. error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

[image: Error Message]

The web part can be used in SPS 2013 but when i try to deploy it to SPF 2013 the error appear.The functionality of this web part is to play an audio that been stored in database using JWPlayer. Below are my piece of code for your review.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MyGSTAudio.MyGSTGaleriAudio
{
public partial class MyGSTGaleriAudioUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ToString();

    public string AudioLoc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudioLocation"].ToString();

    public string ThumbnailLoc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThumbnailLocation"].ToString();

    public string audioName = string.Empty;

    public string currAudioID = String.Empty;

    protected void grdAudio_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        grdAudio.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        ThumbnailValue();
    }



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThumbnailValue();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConn);

            string defaultVid = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ex ORDER BY ID Desc";
            SqlCommand cmdThumbnail = new SqlCommand(defaultVid, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(defaultVid, conn);
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dataset, "ex");

            if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                currAudioID = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            }

            else
            {

                lblNoVideo.Visible = true;

            }
            conn.Close();


            Download.Text = "Click to Download....";

            Page.DataBind();

        }

        String videoPlayPic = "<img src='" + ThumbnailLoc + "playvid.jpg' width='200px' height='150px' />";



    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void image_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton btn1 = sender as ImageButton;

        audioName = btn1.CommandArgument;
        ViewState["currentAudio"] = btn1.CommandArgument;
        Download.CommandArgument = audioName;
        Download.Text = AudioLoc + audioName;
        currAudioID = ViewState["currentAudio"].ToString();
        Page.DataBind();

    }



    protected void link_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;

        audioName = btn.CommandArgument;

        Download.Text = AudioLoc + audioName;
        ViewState["currentAudio"] = btn.CommandArgument;
        Download.Text = "Click to Download....";
        currAudioID = ViewState["currentAudio"].ToString();
        Page.DataBind();


    }

    protected void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton downloadButton = sender as LinkButton;

        audioName = downloadButton.CommandArgument;

        //Page.DataBind();

        //Download.CommandArgument = videoName;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + audioName);
        Response.WriteFile(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\9999\jwplayer\audio\" + audioName);
        //Response.WriteFile(VideoLoc + videoName);
        //VideoLoc
        Response.ContentType = "";
        Response.End();

    }

    private void ThumbnailValue()
    {

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConn);

        string qThumbnail = "SELECT * FROM ex";
        SqlCommand cmdThumbnail = new SqlCommand(qThumbnail, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(qThumbnail, conn);
        conn.Open();
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "ex");

        grdAudio.DataSource = dataset;
        grdAudio.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you need to show us the proper error your getting?

goto sharepoint log files and reproduce the error, coppy the correlation id that it generates and open the most uptodate log file (sort by date) once open search by the copied id and it will show you the error. Post here the error by updating your question.

the error can occure from a few areas that it would generate that.

most likely as its onload the error would be from onload and possibly from ThumbnailValue function your calling. make sure sqlConn is correct (right username and password and domain). also make sure ex exists.

my next area to tackle would be to put try catch block in the onload function:

```
private string strErrortext = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
    ThumbnailValue();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConn);

        string defaultVid = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ex ORDER BY ID Desc";
        SqlCommand cmdThumbnail = new SqlCommand(defaultVid, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(defaultVid, conn);
        conn.Open();
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "ex");

        if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            currAudioID = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
        }

        else
        {

            lblNoVideo.Visible = true;

        }
        conn.Close();


        Download.Text = "Click to Download....";

        Page.DataBind();

    }

    String videoPlayPic = "<img src='" + ThumbnailLoc + "playvid.jpg' width='200px' height='150px' />";

  }
  catch(Exception a)
  {
       strErrortext = ex.Message + ex.Source + ex.StackTrace;
  }

}

    protected override void RenderContents(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strErrortext))
        {
            writer.Write(strErrortext);
        }
        else
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
        }
    }
```

this allows your page to load if an error occures, if it does it will print the error to page instead of throwing the error your getting! I would after testing make it write to event viewer instead and then show a nice message that somthing has gone wrong!